# update set of fields ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible in Ruby (2) and Rails (3.2) to update a selection of fields in a single command. For example, I need to update a set of fields in a hook, where all the names match. I end up with something like this

```
  def set_address
    assign_attributes(address1: subscription.subscriber.address1,
                      address2: subscription.subscriber.address2,
                      address3: subscription.subscriber.address3,
                      city: subscription.subscriber.city,
                      county: subscription.subscriber.county,
                      country_id: subscription.subscriber.country_id,
                      postcode: subscription.subscriber.postcode)
  end
```

given that all the field names match across the two models is there an easier way to do this, or a way to group the fields together so that I can execute

```
def set_address
  address = subscription.subscriber.address
end
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: You can, but it would be better not to. Also how do you know if the two columns are related, even if they have the same name? Surely, you don't want to reassign `id`, `created_at`, etc. You will have to whitelist/blacklist them anyway so better leave it obvious. It is not that much repetition.

Comment: As for the latter request - just make a separate table - `address`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a much better solution here would be to rationalise your database by creating a new table/model: `Address`.  Then you can just do: `address = subscription.subscriber.address`.

Comment: Not a valid solution for an invoice where the address must be as at the time of invoice, not whatever is in another table, which could be updated. For example a company may move address.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
[:address1, :address2, :address3, :city, :country, :country_id, :postcode].each do |field|
  send("#{field}=", subscription.subscriber.send(field))
end
```